# Matrix Determinants Equivalence

Tags: matrices, determinant

[image: My question:]

The left-hand side becomes A*I_n - B*0_n,n = A, correct? How can A = det(A) just from the information given?

Comment: Consider converting image to text; and also [this link](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) will help you learn how to write math in this site.

Comment: The determinant of a block matrix is not a matrix.  The LHS should evaluate to $\det(I_n)\det(A)$.

Comment: This Wikipedia article might come handy: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Use a cofactor expansion along the diagonal of $I$. Look at this small example to see the pattern:
$$
\det\left[\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 &  &  & 2 & 3\\
 & 1 &  & 4 & 5\\
 &  & 1 & 6 & 7\\
 &  &  & 8 & 9\\
 &  &  & 10 & 11
\end{array}\right]=\det\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
1 &  & 4 & 5\\
 & 1 & 6 & 7\\
 &  & 8 & 9\\
 &  & 10 & 11
\end{array}\right]=\det\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 6 & 7\\
 & 8 & 9\\
 & 10 & 11
\end{array}\right]=\det\left[\begin{array}{cc}
8 & 9\\
10 & 11
\end{array}\right]
$$

Comment: So the determinant of the identity matrix is 1. I really have no idea how to continue. All the stuff on the Internet seems like very intimidating theory. What exactly are the steps that I have to take further?

Edit: do I have to use something like induction? For example, showing that it is true for n = 1 and then use induction to prove it in general form?

Comment: Induction is the right way to go. Do you understand the example above?